# In the figure $D$ and $E$ are the mid points of

Tags: geometry

In the figure $D$ and $E$ are the mid points of $AB$ and $AC$ respectively. $F$ and $G$ are two points on $BC$ such that $DG||EF$ then prove that $$2||gm DEFG=\triangle ABC$$

[image]

My Attempt

$$DE||BC$$
$$DE=\frac {1}{2} BC$$
$$DEFG$$ is a parallelogram

$$DE=GF$$

Then what should I do next?

Comment: What does $2||gm DEFG=\triangle ABC$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing I see is to draw a line from $A$ perpendicular to $DE$ and $BC$.  Say this line meets $DE$ at $X$ and meets $BC$ at $Y$.  Then you can express the area of the parallelogram $DEFG$ in terms of $DE$ and $XY$.  And you can express the area of the triangle $ABC$ in terms of $AY$ and $BC$.  But also $XY = \frac{1}{2} AY$, and I think you can fill in the rest.